# Flutter google_sign_in fail to login without code error

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I have an application with google_sign_in, some users can login and others are having the following error (i don't have the full stack because it happened on release and i can't just let the app fail, so i catch it and send it to backend (yes i know is bad but ...)):

```
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:233)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:361)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I look at the code in (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:361) and it fails right in:

```
Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() {
    final Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> result =
        _addMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlatform.instance.signIn, canSkipCall: true);
    bool isCanceled(dynamic error) => error is PlatformException && error.code == kSignInCanceledError; <-------- IT FAILS RIGHT HERE
    return result.catchError((dynamic _) => null, test: isCanceled);
  }
```

Steps to Reproduce:

1. User click to login
2. User select a valid account
3. Error above occurs

I am signin a user using (inside a Future and using catchError):

```
GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```

Some of you might say that the user is cancelling the login BUT when a user cancel a login it throws a PlatformException with a status code 'sign_in_canceled' and i'm already catching this exception. AND i saw the error occur personally!

Additional Information:

1. The SHA1 and SHA256 are correctly set (both from release key, debug
   and the play store).
2. The google-services.json is set.
3. The email are set in firebase to.
4. Oauth consent is set with the icon, name, link to privacy policy.
5. google_sign_in: ^5.0.1

I just need the access_token as i'm send it to my backend in Django using Allauth, as i sayed before, this error only happened with some users (they all have different android versions and devices), i tested with many different android versions and real devices, all worked fine. Because of this i needed to make a manual login (not ideal as i wanna do an one click login ...).

flutter doctor --verbose output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-12.1.pre, on Linux, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.1.0-12.1.pre at /home/alexmi/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 8264cb3e8a (5 weeks ago), 2021-03-10 12:37:57 -0800
    • Engine revision 711ab3fda0
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-116.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/alexmi/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/101/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/101/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 55.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 201.9335
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • moto g 8 power (mobile) • 0069448192 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114

• No issues found!
```

**I found the solution**:
The problem was in the automatically login mechanism, it checks if was previously logged and then log it back, but the way i was doing this was calling it before the user actually logged in, so i thing the login action was triggered multiple times causing to be cancelled.

Comment: Can you please `cd` into `android` folder and run `./gradlew signingReport`, and then confirm the SHA1 and SHA256 displayed are the same as what's in the Firebase Project Settings? I know it sounds silly but doesn't hurt to make sure :-)

Comment: Yep is silly but just for sanity check i did it and it is the same, i already check the play store, the login is working fine for most of the users (including my user)

Comment: Maybe user is doubletapping login button; that can throw that error.

Comment: When a user click on the button to login with google i change the state of the screen to hide everything (with visibility widget) and show a loading on bottom, but i guess if the device get slow enough it could be the case you said @innich i'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: @innich i tested here trying to double tap, none of the devices (including emulator) double tapped. So i pourposely did two calls to signin in one tap and it works fine (just a warning about async/future). So back to the draw board ..